# How can I put my array of countries into a <select> tag?

Tags: php, html, arrays, foreach

So, I'm doing a form in a mix html/php project were I want to have a select tag that gives as options the all list of countries.
I stored my list under an array "countries" as such:

```
$countries = array("Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria", ...."Zambia", "Zimbabwe");
```

and tried to loop within my select tag so that each country would pop up into a option tag.

```
<div class="form-group">
                            <label for="countries" class="col-md-3 control-label">Countries</label>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <select class="form-control" id="countries" name="countries">
                                    <?php foreach ($countries as $country) { ?>
                                        <option value="<?= $countries->country ?>"><?= $countries->country ?></option>
                                    <?php } ?>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-3 error">
                                <?php error('countries'); ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

but what I get is "trying to get property of non-object"

So because I'm not advance in php, I'm kinda blocked with what's happening if anyone is willing to help me. Thank you

Comment: `$countries->country` implies an object. But you define `$countries` as an array. Therefore you should use `<option value="<?= $country ?>"><?= $country ?></option>` ... `$countries->country` would be to a method `country()` that does not exist. You define `$countries` as an array of strings, by appearance. Hence *trying to get property of non-object*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$countries is an array and you are using foreach loop which gets the value of array to $country. You just to echo $country.

```
<div class="form-group">
       <label for="countries" class="col-md-3 control-label">Countries</label>
       <div class="col-md-6">
            <select class="form-control" id="countries" name="countries">
                  <?php foreach ($countries as $country) { ?>
                       <option value="<?= $country ?>"><?= $country ?></option>
                  <?php } ?>
              </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 error">
              <?php error('countries'); ?>
        </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps you :)

Comment: Mentioned the same in comments to your post. But just seeing the same. I am upvoting this solution.

Answer (score 0):

obviously this is the wrong part:

```
<?php foreach ($countries as $country) { ?>
    <option value="<?= $countries->country ?>"><?= $countries->country ?></option>
<?php } ?>
```

because `foreach ($countries as $country)` means "go inside `$countries` and save on each iteration the current element inside `$country`", and so the code should looks like this:

```
<?php foreach ($countries as $country) { ?>
    <option value="<?= $country ?>"><?= $country ?></option>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you loop `$countries as $country` in a [foreach](https://www.php.net/manual/de/control-structures.foreach.php), each element of `$countries` is saved in `$country` in every instance of the loop.

That means, to print each country, a loop looks like this:

```
foreach ($countries as $country) {
  echo $country;
}
```

Comment: OP is confused on syntax in thinking that an array property has its own similarly named "getter" by default which it doesnt actually.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to just use a for loop. Given the array `$countries`, you can do this:

```
<select name="country">
<?php
$ct = count($countries)
for($i=0;$i<=$ct;$i++){
$country = $countries[$i];
echo "<option value='$country'>$country</option>";
}
?>
</select>
```

Hope this helps.